# Trouble Scraping BigFuture in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to use rvest to scrape https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/princeton-university to get the link to the college (CSS selector says #cpProfile_ataglance_collegeGeneralUrl_anchor) and some text off of the international students section (can be accessed through the sidebar). html_nodes() is being unable to read in this information to R no matter what I try. I've tried to use the developer tools option in chrome to get the information but even that isn't working. What am I missing?

```
base_url = "https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/princeton-university"
page = read_html(base_url)
page %>%
  html_nodes("#cpProfile_ataglance_collegeGeneralUrl_anchor")
```

Comment: `"#cpProfile_ataglance_collegeGeneralUrl_anchor" %in% page[2]` says `FALSE` - it doesn't see that tag on that page. Nothing starting with `#cpProfile` at all.

Comment: I see. I have no idea what else to do; this is the output that my CSS selector gives me. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page is generated with javascript. You can use  `RSelenium` package to open a browser in which the page is generated and, after that, read the html and scrape what you want (just like you were doing):

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
base_url = "https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/princeton-university"
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(base_url)
page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
page %>% html_nodes("#cpProfile_ataglance_collegeGeneralUrl_anchor")
```